# Não consigo exibir minhas paginas html com Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou tentando exibir minhas paginas html dentro do meu Layout principal porém sempre da erro 404:

> Error: Not Found
>       at C:\Users\Adiego\Documents\ProjetoNode\sistema1\app.js:36:13

Esse é o meu app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var load =  require('express-load');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//var routes = require('./routes/index');
//var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



load('models').then('controllers').then('routes').into(app);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

imagem do erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como é que estás a correr a app? `node index.js`? ou outra maneira?

Comment: Você precisa postar suas rotas e com qual url está tentando acessa-las. Só com essas informações não dá para ajudar.

Comment: O erro estava nas rotas mesmo kk, fui la dar uma olhada após você ter falado e encontrei o erro. Coloque uma resposta para que eu possa marca-la como correta

Comment: Você precisa definir as rotas corretamente. O Erro provavelmente é esse. Importante sempre checar as rotas, evita dores de cabeça.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde Diego,

Ao fazer isso:

> ```
> // catch 404 and forward to error handler
> app.use(function(req, res, next) {
>   var err = new Error('Not Found');
>   err.status = 404;
>   next(err);
> });
> ```

No express, você está dizendo que para cada conexão que entrar, não importa do que se trate, você vai criar o Error('Not Found') e repassá-lo para a próxima rotina de tratamento.

Se ninguém a frente pegar, ele irá para o client (browser no caso do seu exemplo).

Para que isso não ocorra, você tem que ter tratado a requisição antes disso, ou seja, seu problema está em algum lugar aqui:

> ```
> load('models').then('controllers').then('routes').into(app);
> ```

Se seus modelos, controllers ou rotas estiverem tratando, eles não devem chamar a rotina 'next' ao final, para que o tratamento pare por ali. Se for uma requisição que não foi tratada por ninguém ela cairá no 404 definido.

Espero ter ajudado.